# how to download depth data from TRTH/datascope using Python REST API?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

I am trying to download depth data from Tick History Market Depth/Legacy market depth using REST API from this [post](https://github.com/TR-API-Samples/Article.TRTH.Python.REST.OndemandRequestTimeAndSales).

As you already know, depth data is quite large. so I would like to save the files by date. i.e. instead of having 1 giant file, I have one file for each day that contains depth data for all stocks in the list. I would also love to separate by stock and then by date as well but by date is fine for now.

How would I go about it? The following is my code. I use Python 3.6 with Pycharm by the way. And I am not really good with Python. I normally use SAS. While the code is long, there are 4 big parts:

```
    1. A JSON file that specifies the fields to download
    2. a RequestNewToken function to get token each time
    3. A function that extracts data
    4. A main function that runs the above 2 functions
```

1. The JSON file that specifies the fields to download

> ```
> {
>   "ExtractionRequest": {
>     "@odata.type": "#ThomsonReuters.Dss.Api.Extractions.ExtractionRequests.TickHistoryMarketDepthExtractionRequest",
>     "ContentFieldNames": [
>       "Ask Price",
>       "Ask Size",
>       "Bid Price",
>       "Bid Size"
>     ],
>     "IdentifierList": {
>         "@odata.type": "#ThomsonReuters.Dss.Api.Extractions.ExtractionRequests.InstrumentListIdentifierList",
>         "InstrumentListId":"0x06698c5d00301db4"
>      },
>     "Condition": {
>       "View": "NormalizedLL2",
>       "NumberOfLevels": 5,
>       "MessageTimeStampIn": "GmtUtc",
>       "ReportDateRangeType": "Range",
>       "QueryStartDate": "1996-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
>       "QueryEndDate": "2018-06-06T23:59:59.999Z",
>       "DisplaySourceRIC": "True"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> 2. Here is the code to run and get data:

```
> _outputFilePath="./"
> _outputFileName="TestOutput"
> _retryInterval=int(30) #value in second used by Pooling loop to check request status on the server
> _jsonFileName="TickHistoricalRequest.json"
> 
> def RequestNewToken(username="",password=""):
>     _AuthenURL = "https://hosted.datascopeapi.reuters.com/RestApi/v1/Authentication/RequestToken"
>     _header= {}
>     _header['Prefer']='respond-async'
>     _header['Content-Type']='application/json; odata.metadata=minimal'
>     _data={'Credentials':{
>         'Password':password,
>         'Username':username
>         }
>     }
> 
>     print("Send Login request")
>     resp=post(_AuthenURL,json=_data,headers=_header)
> 
> 
>     if resp.status_code!=200:
>         message="Authentication Error Status Code: "+ str(resp.status_code) +" Message:"+dumps(loads(resp.text),indent=4)
>         raise Exception(str(message))
> 
>     return loads(resp.text)['value']
> 
> 
> def ExtractRaw(token,json_payload):
>     try:
>         _extractRawURL="https://hosted.datascopeapi.reuters.com/RestApi/v1/Extractions/ExtractRaw"
>         #Setup Request Header
>         _header={}
>         _header['Prefer']='respond-async'
>         _header['Content-Type']='application/json; odata.metadata=minimal'
>         _header['Accept-Charset']='UTF-8'
>         _header['Authorization']='Token'+token
> 
>         #Post Http Request to DSS server using extract raw URL
>         resp=post(_extractRawURL,data=None,json=json_payload,headers=_header)
> 
> 
>         #Print Status Code return from HTTP Response
>         print("Status Code="+str(resp.status_code) )
> 
> 
>         #Raise exception with error message if the returned status is not 202 (Accepted) or 200 (Ok)
>         if resp.status_code!=200:
>             if resp.status_code!=202:
>                 message="Error: Status Code:"+str(resp.status_code)+" Message:"+resp.text
>                 raise Exception(message)
> 
> 
>             #Get location from header, URL must be https so we need to change it using string replace function
>             _location=str.replace(resp.headers['Location'],"http://","https://")
> 
> 
>             print("Get Status from "+str(_location))
>             _jobID=""
> 
> 
>             #pooling loop to check request status every 2 sec.
>             while True:
>                 resp=get(_location,headers=_header)
>                 _pollstatus = int(resp.status_code)
> 
> 
>                 if _pollstatus==200:
>                     break
>                 else:
>                     print("Status:"+str(resp.headers['Status']))
>                 sleep(_retryInterval) #wait for _retyInterval period and re-request the status to check if it already completed
> 
> 
>         # Get the jobID from HTTP response
>         json_resp = loads(resp.text)
>         _jobID = json_resp.get('JobId')
>         print("Status is completed the JobID is "+ str(_jobID)+ "\n")
> 
> 
>         # Check if the response contains Notes.If the note exists print it to console.
>         if len(json_resp.get('Notes')) > 0:
>             print("Notes:\n======================================")
>             for var in json_resp.get('Notes'):
>                 print(var)
>             print("======================================\n")
> 
> 
>         # Request should be completed then Get the result by passing jobID to RAWExtractionResults URL
>         _getResultURL = str("https://hosted.datascopeapi.reuters.com/RestApi/v1/Extractions/RawExtractionResults(\'"
> + _jobID + "\')/$value")
>         print("Retrieve result from " + _getResultURL)
>         resp=get(_getResultURL,headers=_header,stream=True)
> 
> 
>         #Write Output to file.
>         outputfilepath = str(_outputFilePath + _outputFileName + str(os.getpid()) + '.csv.gz')
>         if resp.status_code==200:
>             with open(outputfilepath, 'wb') as f:
>                 f.write(resp.raw.read())
> 
> 
>         print("Write output to "+outputfilepath+" completed\n\n")
>         print("Below is sample data from "+ outputfilepath)
>         #Read data from csv.gz and shows output from dataframe head() and tail() 
>         df=pd.read_csv(outputfilepath,compression='gzip')
>         print(df.head())
>         print("....")
>         print(df.tail())
> 
> 
>     except Exception as ex:
>         print("Exception occrus:", ex)
> 
> 
>     return
> 
>
> 
> def main():
>     try:
>         #Request a new Token
>         print("Login to DSS Server")
>         _DSSUsername=input('Enter DSS Username:')
>         try:
>             _DSSPassword=getpass(prompt='Enter DSS Password:')
>             _token=RequestNewToken(_DSSUsername,_DSSPassword)
>         except GetPassWarning as e:
>              print(e)
>         print("Token="+_token+"\n")
> 
> 
>         #Read the HTTP request body from JSON file. So you can change the request in JSON file instead.
>         queryString = {}
>         with open(_jsonFileName, "r") as filehandle:
>             queryString=load(filehandle,object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
> 
> 
>         #print(queryString)
>         ExtractRaw(_token,queryString)
> 
> 
>     except Exception as e:
>         print(e)
> 
> 
> print(__name__)
> 
> 
> if __name__=="__main__":
>     main()
```